# How to extract specific <li> element using Xpath?

Tags: parsing, xpath, html-lists

There is a list:

```
<ul class="params">
     <li> <span>Brand:</span> Casio </li>                  
     <li> <span>Gender:</span> male </li>           
     <li> <span>Material:</span> metal </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to extract specific "Gender" parameter. So I want to extract `<li>` element that has this information:

```
<span>Gender:</span> male
```

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
//ul[@class="params"]/li[text()[contains(.,'Gender')]]
```

Not working.

How to extract this specific `<li>` element?

Comment: `gender` and `Gender` are different.

Comment: anyway this code doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Gender:" is a child of `span`, not `li`:

```
 //ul[@class="params"]/li[span="Gender:"]
```